# How to convert string to pem?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

as part of automation in pipeline.

i am passing the ssh key pem file content as variable value.

The echo seems to show exact content but the file written back is not doing ssh

```
echo $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_key.pem
chmod 400 ssh_key.pem
```

Below is the context.
The ssh_key.pem works fine normally.
But, as I am using this in a pipeline of gitlab(or any CI server).
I am passing the ssh_key.pem content as a string.

The string value picked in input parameter($ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY) is written to a pem file and when I echo that, the data is identical.But getting permission denied error.

ssh is giving permission denied

Comment: You say that "ssh is giving permission denied". What is the ssh line that you run, which user's rights does ssh use?

Comment: added details, can you check that

Comment: You write that you are using this in a pipeline. However, the code given in your question writes to a file ... how does it go to the $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY variable? Also, what does the part look like where ssh is getting the key. My first guess is that the input is understood as filename (or something like that) instead of pipelined input.

Comment: I do not think that the background details are unneccessary. You said that you receive a "permission denied error" which leads me to the well-grounded assumption, that nothing is wrong with the string/PEM, but that the problem occurs in the subsequent step.

Comment: You can give a try from your end by reading a pem file to variable and writing it back as file in bash and use that to connect.

Comment: Please note that this is no commercial support platform ;) If you have a problem and want help, it is useful to state the problem as accurate as possible. The fact that nobody else has yet bothered to answer your question, is a sign that important information is in fact missing. What you code does, is writing a file and setting its permissions. If `less ssh_key.pem` shows you that the content is in the file, than this part has worked, and there is nothing to help you with.